# Efficient sampling from Gaussian

Tags: python, numpy, random, sampling, normal-distribution

I'm trying to efficiently sample from a "high-dimensional" normal distribution with mean μm and covariance Σ.  What I do know is that Σ = x^T x for some known vector x.
I can *naively* do it in numpy via something like:

**Generate dummy inputs:**

```
N = 10**2
m = np.ones(N)
x = np.ones(N)
```

**Perform random sampling:**

```
C = np.matmul(x[:,None], x[None,:])
A = np.random.multivariate_normal(m, C, 1).T
```

However, when N is extremly large, say `10^7` then this becomes infeasible to store x^Tx.  Are there known tricks to sample in this case without having to compute and store x^Tx?

Comment: `np.transpose(x)` doesn't change 1D array. I guess you mean `x[:,None] * x` instead of matmul.

Comment: or `np.matmul(x[:,None], x[None,:])`?

Comment: It does.  I'll take down my post